# jQuery click event function remembering the parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

The Javascript/jQuery code below will output three divs with the numbers 1, 2 and 3. However when clicking any of the divs it will alert the number 3 always.

How would I write it so that it will alert the "correct"  number. *Without putting the number into the HTML itself.*

```
var values = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i in values) {
    var element = $("<div>" + values[i] + "</div>");

  $("body").append(element);

  element.click(function() { alert(values[i]); });
}
```

Comment: Would you be comfortable storing the data not as the html string but as jQuery data attached to the element itself?

Comment: That's a closure issue. At time you click and call handler, the `i` as last value.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use a `for...in` loop for an array-- it is only meant to be used for iterating over keys in an object.  If you need to iterate over an array, use a standard `for` loop, or `forEach` if you're so inclined.

Comment: A better dupe would have been http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: try this instead: `var element = $("<div />",{"class":"clickme","data-value":values[i]}).text(values[i]);` and add `$("body").on("click",".clickme",function() { alert($(this).data("value"));});`

Comment: @epascarello I actually do not agree. The dupe I posted shows the exact code to use, whereas your dupe is a huge post with much information that is worth reading but harder to match to the problem at hand

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it:

```
var values = [1, 2, 3];

function clickHandler(event) {
  alert(event.target.innerHTML);
}

for (var i in values) {
    var element = $("<div>" + values[i] + "</div>");

  $("body").append(element);

  element.click(clickHandler);
}
```

Comment: You beat me by a couple of seconds.  Your code works.  

:)


https://jsfiddle.net/j7q0vswL/

Comment: But what if for some reason (?!) the appended element doesn't only contains the `values[i]`??? This is really not a reliable way to handle it. You'd have better at least to set some custom data attribute

Comment: it's all about perspective. you saw it from a different view and i saw it from a different view :)

Comment: @jonLuci But the question wasn't how to get appended DIVs content :) I guess it was just a minimalistic sample OP posted

Answer (score 1):

So, to avoid closure issue, you could wrap your binding inside a IIFE:

```
var values = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i in values) {
  var element = $("<div>" + values[i] + "</div>");

  $("body").append(element);

  (function(i) { // 'i' is local to anonymous function block
    element.click(function() {
      alert(values[i]);
    });
  }(i));
}
```

Comment: this could be solved even without closure :)

Comment: Since the OP question is obviously a simplified example, this trick to avoid closure effect is good to know.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Ya, but the best one (when fully implemented by all browsers) would be to use function scope, using `let`: https://jsfiddle.net/sa1L2ckr/  Now actually, only Opera Mini doesn't implement it, if that really matters

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var values = [1, 2, 3];
for (var i in values) {
  var element = $("<div>" + values[i] + "</div>");
  $("body").append(element);
```

}

```
$("div").click(function() { 
   alert($(this).text()); 
});
```

Hope it will be useful

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i in values) {
    var element = $("<div>" + values[i] + "</div>");

  $("body").append(element);

  element.click(function() { alert(this.innerHTML); });
}
```

The most simple solution: Read .innerHTML